# Bypass optional field in pattern match

Tags: perl

I'm trying to pull out the names of the players and totals, but in some cases there is an extra html tag following the number of the player in the list.  So how can I bypass that extra field when it appears.  I can't put parenthesis around it because it will try to match it, correct?

```
<tr><td>10<td>MANNY MACHADO - FA</td><td>37</td></tr>
<tr><td>107</td><td>ALEDMYS DIAZ - HOU</td><td>18</td></tr>

while($content =~ /<tr><td>\d+?\S+?<td>(.*?)\s-.*?<\/td><td>(\d+?)</g) {
  my $player = $1;
  my $total = $2;
  print "\nPlayer => $player  Total => $total\n";
}
```

I tried using the '\S+?' to bypass it, but in this case it doesn't print out anything where the number of the player is less than 10.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally a **bad** idea to use regexes for HTML, XML, etc.

Instead you should use an appropriate parser to convert it to a DOM and then implement your algorithm in the DOM domain. Using your example:

- parse the HTML from file or string
- (find the correct table in the document - left out in the example as I don't have the complete HTML)
- loop over the rows in the table
- extract the information you are looking for from the columns of a row

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $parser = new HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $root = $parser->parse_file(\*DATA)
    or die "HTML\n";

foreach my $row ($root->look_down(_tag => 'tr')) {
    if (my @columns = $row->look_down(_tag => 'td')) {
        my $player  = $columns[1]->as_text();
        my $total   = $columns[2]->as_text();
        print "Player => $player  Total => $total\n";
    }
}

exit 0;

__DATA__
<body>
  <tr><td>10<td>MANNY MACHADO - FA</td><td>37</td></tr>
  <tr><td>107</td><td>ALEDMYS DIAZ - HOU</td><td>18</td></tr>
</body>
```

Test run:

```
$ perl dummy.pl
Player => MANNY MACHADO - FA  Total => 37
Player => ALEDMYS DIAZ - HOU  Total => 18
```

Comment: Personally, I'd rather `->find()` than `->look_down(_tag => )`

Comment: @Dada I agree that in this particular case `find()` will be simpler. But `look_down()` is more generic, e.g. `look_down(_tag => 'table', class => qr/some-table/, ...)`. In my experience screenscraping real-world HTML requires more than just the tag name.

Comment: Oh, `look_down` is definitely more generic. And `find` won't indeed get you far on real-world HTML. I just personally prefer using `find` when I'm only interested in the tag (feels more lightweight, and with a more obvious semantics). But  it's just a matter of tastes I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

With [Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Mojo::DOM;

my $html = <<'EOD';
<tr><td>10<td>MANNY MACHADO - FA</td><td>37</td></tr>
<tr><td>107</td><td>ALEDMYS DIAZ - HOU</td><td>18</td></tr>
EOD

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($html);
foreach my $tr ($dom->find('tr')->each) {
  my @cells = $tr->children('td')->each;
  my $player = $cells[1]->all_text;
  my $total = $cells[2]->all_text;

  # or alternatively
  my $player = $tr->at('td:nth-of-type(2)')->all_text;
  my $total = $tr->at('td:nth-of-type(3)')->all_text;

  print "\nPlayer => $player  Total => $total\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to match an optional `</tr>`, so You can do that with the following `(?:<\/tr>)?` in your regex. This makes a non capturing group, because of the `?:` at the start, that matches 0 or 1 times. So your new regex is

```
/<tr><td>\d+(?:<\/td>)?<td>(.*?)\s-.*?<\/td><td>(\d+?)</g
```

Normally I'd add a bit about not using regex to parse HTML, but as this is not well formed HTML I'll let it pass. However if you can exercise some control over what is creating the HTML try and fix it so that the `<td>` and `</td>` tags are balanced.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also someone who would go for a proper HTML or XML modul to extract information like others above already said. So I will not elaborate on that.

If I would have to extract from the wrongly formatted html you showed, I'd stick with a multi step aproach.

1. cleanup
2. extract
3. more cleanup

For cleanup I'd first check what's common. In this case every line starts with `<tr>` so I'd settle for that to find my lines, skipping those not starting with `<tr>`, after some optional whitespace:

```
while (<>) {
    next unless /^\s*<tr>/;
```

The next common thing I noticed is that every interesting field starts with `td`. So I'd replace it with something more easy like a tab. Assuming there could be tabs already, I'd first replace them with spaces:

```
    tr/\t/ /;
    s/<td>/\t/g;
```

Now what I have is some tags sprinkled around the data I really need. And the data I really need is prepended with a tab. So let's delete the tags:

```
    s/<.*?>//g;
```

Finally I can extract my data:

```
    my($dummy, $number, $player, $total)= split /\t/;
```

But since the player has some stuff appended (after `-`) let's remove that as well

```
    $player=~ s/\s-.*//;
    print "\nPlayer => $player  Total => $total\n";
}
```

Putting it together and using DATA:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    next unless /^\s*<tr>/;
    tr/\t/ /;
    s/<td>/\t/g;
    s/<.*?>//g;
    my($dummy, $number, $player, $total)= split /\t/;
    $player=~ s/\s-.*//;
    print "\nPlayer => $player  Total => $total\n";
}
__DATA__
<tr><td>10<td>MANNY MACHADO - FA</td><td>37</td></tr>
<tr><td>107</td><td>ALEDMYS DIAZ - HOU</td><td>18</td></tr>
```

Please be prepared that you might come across data with more whitespace and the approach will fail.

Example:

```
<tr>
  <td>10
  <td>MANNY MACHADO - FA</td>
  <td>37</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>107</td>
    <td>ALEDMYS DIAZ - HOU</td>
    <td>18</td>
</tr>
```